# How to use the index method efficiently

Tags: python, indexing, slice

I have recently started learning Python, and I received a question: "Write a Python program that asks the user to enter full name in the following format:

LastName, FirstName MiddleName

(for Example: "Hun, Attila The”).

The input will have a single space after the comma and only a single space between the first name and the middle name. Use string methods and operators in Python to convert this to a new string having the form:

FirstName MiddleInitial Period LastName (for example: "Attila T. Hun") and output it."

It is easy for me to do this if I make three different variables, and then reorder/slice them later. But how do I do this in one variable only. I know I will need to slice up until "," for the LastName, but I can't do "[0:,]" as I am not using an integer value, so how do i find the integer value for it, if the lastName will vary from user to user.

Comment: You may want to consider using other string methods such as [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Comment: In general: use variables.  Use as many as you need to express yourself.  They cost nothing and your code is more readable if you give every operation its own line.  Sure, it's possible be "clever" and do this in one line with some regex or chained `split` and slicing, but all that buys is less maintainable, harder to read code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `index`, use `split` and split on the various separators. E.g., `full_name.split(', ')[0] == 'Hun'`, `full_name.split(', ')[1] == 'Attila'`, and `full_name.split(' ')[-1] == 'The'`. You can then easily recombine them with string formatting or simple concatenation.

Comment: @UmerMuhammad its not problem that you remove your tick but when you find an answer useful you can tell that to community with upvote !

Comment: @kasra ill definitely remember to do that in the future, sorry

Comment: @Rotten194 its a lot easier to use splits, but although i can use whichever methods to get the same output, the assignment question tells me to specifically use the index method. Would you be able to give me a lead for that? following the same format, i came up with this, which allows me to get the last name, but i get stuck with the rest of it:                   <code>name = input("please enter: ")
lastname = int(name.index(', '))           print(name[0:lastname])</code>

Answer (score 0):

First if you are in `python 2.x` use `raw_input()` if `python 3.x` use `input()` , So you can split with `space` and then ramove `,` at the end of last name !

ex:

```
fullname=raw_input("enter your full name by this format (LastName, FirstName MiddleName)")
    >>> separate_names=[name[:-1] if ',' in name else name for name in fullname.split(' ') ]
>>> separate_names #if fullname=="Hun, Attila The”
['Hun', 'Attila', 'The']
```

also you can add it in a dictionary :

```
>>> dict(zip(['LastName','FirstName', 'MiddleName'] ,separate_names))
{'MiddleName': 'The', 'LastName': 'Hun', 'FirstName': 'Attila'}
```